# Who would investigate whether the UK PM broke the ministerial code?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament

My understanding is that if it is in the public knowledge that someone is suspected to be committing a crime/fraud, they will at least get investigated, and then brought to justice if enough evidence found.

My question is about the recent [video by Peter Stevanovic](https://twitter.com/PeterStefanovi2/status/1423166870321045504?s=20) that is almost on 31 million views, claiming the PM has lied in the parliament multiple times, wouldn't we expect an investigation on whether the PM broke the ministerial code?

What authority would be responsible for taking such action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where there are alleged breaches of the code, these can be investigated by an independent adviser on ministerial interests or by the cabinet secretary.  The current independent adviser is [Lord Geidt](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/the-rt-hon-lord-geidt-appointed-as-independent-adviser-on-ministers-interests). Ultimately it is a matter for the Prime Minister and the Cabinet to decide. The code itself is quite clear

> It is not the role of the Cabinet Secretary or other officials
> to enforce the Code. If there is an allegation about a breach of
> the Code, and the Prime Minister, having consulted the Cabinet
> Secretary, feels that it warrants further investigation, he may
> ask the Cabinet Office to investigate the facts of the case
> and/or refer the matter to the independent adviser on Ministers’
> interests.

However, the terms of service of Lord Geidt allow that if he "believes an allegation
about a breach of the Code might warrant further investigation, he will raise the issue
confidentially with the Prime Minister."

As you see, the Ministerial code is not a "law for ministers", with an independent police force.  It is a set of guidelines by which the PM can hold ministers accountable.

- [Institute for government explainer on the Code](https://www.instituteforgovernment.org.uk/explainers/ministerial-code)
- [The ministerial code 2019](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/826920/August-2019-MINISTERIAL-CODE-FINAL-FORMATTED-2.pdf)
- [Lord Geidt terms of service](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/981552/Independent_Adviser_-_Terms_of_Reference_-_April_2021.pdf)

Comment: Which makes it all the more pointless seeing as how the PM (the one accused of lying) is the one who has the power to investigate - much like marking your own homework.